# URL characters replacement in JSP with UrlRewrite

Tags: jsp, jboss, url-rewriting

I am using **[UrlRewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)** in a **JSP** project over **JBoss**. I have configured some rules, so that stuff like:

```
http://mysite/parameter
```

Is read as:

```
http://mysite/index.jsp?parameter=parameter
```

And so on.

Now, what I would like to know if there's a way to replace certain characters submitted in the URL by the users with others. Something like what Wikipedia does. When you use a space in the URL in WikiPedia, it's replaced by a "-".

Is UrlRewrite the right tool for this? I also have a few filters around, but I guess I shoul be able to accomplish this with UrlRewrite or a similar tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs to do this same thing, I've [found out it's possible using Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359147/mask-urls-in-jsp) to filter URLs, response.sendRedirect() and request.getRequestDispatcher().forward().