# Passing special Characters from JSP to Controller

Tags: jsp, encoding, spring-mvc, web.xml

I have some fields with special characters. When I pass those fields from JSP by submiting the form to Springs Controller then it is displayed as shown below.

```
á - Ã¡
é - Ã©
í - Ã
ó - Ã³
ú - Ãº
ñ - Ã±
```

I tried few things like putting some encoding in web.xml,

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Encoding in Controller like,

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Still I am not able to solve the issue. Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I checked some of the questions related this question in our stackoverflow, Still not able to find it. [Character encoding JSP -displayed wrong in JSP but not in URL: "á » Ã¡ é » Ã©"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374573/character-encoding-jsp-displayed-wrong-in-jsp-but-not-in-url-a-a-e-a)

Comment: Is it `get` or `post` query? Do you have some other filters? Also see http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: @axtavt: Thanks a lot buddy, this solved my problem. I added Filters in web.xml and kept method 'post' and everything is working fine. Please post this as answer will approve.

Comment: I don't think it's an answer on its own.

Comment: hmm... but suggestion helps. Anyway thanks buddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This filter works for POST requests only. For GET requests you'd need to configure it at servletcontainer level. In case of for example Apache Tomcat, you'd need to edit the `<Connector>` entry in `/conf/server.xml` to add the `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` attribute.

```xml
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" ... />
```

Calling `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` manually has no effect as the filter is already doing that.