# entering chinese value but show garbage in mysql workbench

Tags: java

```
private EntryContentTable entryContentTable ;
private String ent_content_type;
private String entry_con_val;
private String entry_con_tag;
private int ent_con_hide;

public String execute(){
    String flag=INPUT;

    System.out.println("hello");
    try {
        session=ConnectionProvider.getSession();
        transaction=session.beginTransaction();

        entryContentTable=new EntryContentTable();

        entryContentTable.setEntry_cont_type(getEnt_content_type());
        entryContentTable.setEntry_cont_value(getEntry_con_val());
        entryContentTable.setEntry_cont_tag_name(getEntry_con_tag());

        session.save(entryContentTable);
        transaction.commit();
        flag = SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        return flag;
    }

}
public String entconupdate() {
     String flag=SUCCESS; 
    try{
        System.out.println("HIde Value mmmmmmmmm  ::: " +  ent_con_hide);
         session=ConnectionProvider.getSession();
         transaction=session.beginTransaction();

         entryContentTable=(EntryContentTable)session.load(EntryContentTable.class, ent_con_hide);


         entryContentTable.setEntry_cont_type(getEnt_content_type());
            entryContentTable.setEntry_cont_value(getEntry_con_val());
            entryContentTable.setEntry_cont_tag_name(getEntry_con_tag());

            session.update(entryContentTable);

            transaction.commit();

        return flag;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception in update ECMA Action :: " + e.toString());
        flag = INPUT ; 
        return flag;
    }


}
@Override
public void setSession(Map map) {
    this.sessionmap = map;

}
public String getEnt_content_type() {
    return ent_content_type;
}
public void setEnt_content_type(String ent_content_type) {
    this.ent_content_type = ent_content_type;
}
public String getEntry_con_val() {
    return entry_con_val;
}
public void setEntry_con_val(String entry_con_val) {
    this.entry_con_val = entry_con_val;
}
public String getEntry_con_tag() {
    return entry_con_tag;
}
public void setEntry_con_tag(String entry_con_tag) {
    this.entry_con_tag = entry_con_tag;
}
public EntryContentTable getEntryContentTable() {
    return entryContentTable;
}
public void setEntryContentTable(EntryContentTable entryContentTable) {
    this.entryContentTable = entryContentTable;
}
public int getEnt_con_hide() {
    return ent_con_hide;
}
public void setEnt_con_hide(int ent_con_hide) {
    this.ent_con_hide = ent_con_hide;
}
```

}

this is my java class , i am entering chinese values through jsp pages but it is showing garbage
value in database which is mysql workbench.
 i read xml file for chinese data but jsp pages is not showing chinese data=?

Comment: This is almost certainly going to be a character encoding issue somewhere.  It could be during the form submission; during the processing on the server; during the persistence to the database; or in the database column's own definition.  You'd need to check what each step expects the character set to be, and whether they render the characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To debug...

1. Load the XML file into a XML editor like Notepad++ that supports Unicode.
2. Make sure that your JSP file is explicitly stating that its returning Unicode. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374573/character-encoding-jsp-displayed-wrong-in-jsp-but-not-in-url-a-a-e-a) is a starting point for that with JSP.
3. Make sure that your MySQL tables are using Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Please use UTF8 character encoding for this, to make sure you are using correct fetch metadata of your database AND tables.

For tables check with command:

```
show create table table_name;
```