# Different behaviour of GET and POST related to German "Umlaute"

Tags: jsp, tomcat, post

I'm using JSP on a Apache Tomcat 7.0.41 and want to transfer Form-Data to another page.

For some reasons the German "Umlaute" work if I use GET, but don't if I use POST.
Examples:

> @€ --> @â¬
>
> äöüß --> Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã
>
> Österreich --> Ãsterreich

So I wrote a small Script which uses the recommended `encodeURIComponent()`-JS-Function:

```
function onsubmitfu() {
            tas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
            for (index = 0; index < tas.length; index++) {
                tas[index].innerHTML = encodeURIComponent()(tas[index].innerHTML);
            }
            tas = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (index = 0; index < tas.length; index++) {
                tas[index].value = encodeURIComponent(tas[index].value);
            }
        }
```

And well, it "changes"...

> äöüß€ --> Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ãâ¬

Some sources on the Internet prefer `escape()` so I gave it a try and it works how it is supposed to work but on the wrong side... Now the JSP-Page receives:

> äöüß€ --> %E4%F6%FC%DF%u20AC

This looks how it would be supposed to look in the URL I guess...

Both pages use

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Yet I don't understand why there are differences in the behavior of these two variants.
Is there a workaround?

Comment: It seems `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` is important to always put before the first reading of the request-Parameters. 
A couple of days before I had the same issue but used this command to dowdy. Now it works.
The earlier you put it the better it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Tomcat server set to handle UTF8 characters? This is how I do it in Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu 12.04. This should give you an idea of how to handle.

First, I open up the main Tomcat server XML file like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/tomcat6/server.xml
```

Then I look for the `<Connector` section and make sure it contains `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`. It looks like this by default:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

But should look something like this when you add the `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to it:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Then restart Tomcat 6 like so:

```
sudo service tomcat6 restart.
```

And see what happens. Additionally, please see the suggestions in [this question and answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374573/character-encoding-jsp-displayed-wrong-in-jsp-but-not-in-url-a-a-e-a?rq=1). This programatic answer seems to address the issue:

```
if(request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: You were completely right related to the Tomcat.
 (I just found it in a different directory: /apache-tomcat-7.0.41/conf$ )

Unfortunately there are no changes :-/
On regular submit the results remain the same and encodeURIComponent behaves like "escape"...

Comment: if(request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
}

Solved it!! I guess the combination made it.
Thank you!!!